# Exception has occurred. RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1)

Tags: flutter, api

I was  trying fetch api data with provider, but I am getting this error

Exception has occurred.
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1),

I was using  previously listviewbuilder,so that I can access the data with index, but here I am not getting the idea, please guide me

```
class _MiddleSectionState extends State<MiddleSection> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    getdata();

    super.initState();
  }

  getdata() async {
    likesdata = await Repos().getdata();
  }

  bool isLikebuttonPressed = false;
  List<LikeModelData> likesdata = [];

  @override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final likedData = Provider.of<CommentPageProvider>(context);
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => CommentPageProvider(),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Container(
            width: size.width * 0.2,
            height: size.height * 0.1,
            child: Column(children: [
              Consumer<CommentPageProvider>(
                builder: (context, value, child) {


                  return Row(
                    children: [
                      TextWidgetCommentpage(
                          text: value.isLoading?   likesdata[0].postId ?? "Likes ":  'data fetching'  ),
                      //  TextWidgetCommentpage(text:likesdata[0].postId.toString() ??"11"),
                      const Spacer(),
                      TextWidgetCommentpage(
                          text: '${widget.commentCount}  comments')
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
```

error showing is Exception has occurred.
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1)

Answer (score 2):

Beacause `likesdata` is `null`. You need to use `setState` to update value.

```
 getdata() async {
     setState(() { // use it like this
     likesdata = await Repos().getdata();
    }); 
  }
```

Calling `setState` notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree.

Comment: I am using provider package, so I updated with  ``` TextWidgetCommentpage(
                          text: value.isLoading?   likesdata[0].postId ?? "Likes ":  'data fetching'  ),

Comment: but data is not fetching ,

Comment: because value.isLoading is getting true and after that code tries to find likesdata[0] and code is unable to get record that at 0 index thats why it happens.

Comment: I think you should use loader or progress indicator while data fetching. Once data is fetched you can fetch records without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in 'likesdata' list has no data means that this list is empty that's why you are getting an error like this you also check whether the list is empty or not by putting print in the build method. Please handle the widget view as if

```
   likesdata.isEmpty?SizedBox():YourWidgets()
```

and also API data getting let after build then you need to use
setState after the fatching data

```
   likesdata = await Repos().getdata();
   setState((){});
```